# Is there any way to know whether my Android Application Update can be a manual update or automatic update on google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I am moving to API 24 on Android. I am not adding new permissions or anything for my update. Does google play tell us in advance whether the update will be manual or automatic?

NOTE - Assume user has automatic update apps setting turned on.

Answer (score 0):

It depends only on the user's preferences. They can set if they want to install the apps automatically or manually.

Comment: Well lets assume that user has automatically update setting turned on. Even then some apps need manual permission to upload.

Answer (score 0):

if you think your update is necessary for user, you could choose automatically. BUT it depends on user. if they turn on the automatically yeah it will installed automatically on their device else it will be installed if user install the update manually